# DHCPv6 timeout preferred valid

Tags: dhcpv6

Can someone tell me what this means, and how to fix it?  Ubuntu 18.04.

```
Dec  4 14:37:16 myserver systemd-networkd[28369]: enp2s0: DHCPv6 address xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx::49/128 timeout preferred 3600 valid 3600
```

Lots of these in the log.